# HTC One detected as CD Drive

Tags: windows, usb-debugging, htc-one-x, mtp

I am experiencing a similar problem as described [there](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66773/how-can-i-enable-usb-debugging-on-my-htc-one-with-android-4-4): Whenever I connect my HTC One to my Windows 8.1, it is recognized as a CD Drive. 
So I tried the solution proposed by [Macha's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66773/how-can-i-enable-usb-debugging-on-my-htc-one-with-android-4-4/66857#66857), but I cannot perform the step "Select Standard USB main controller" as I get only CD-Drives proposed int he selection no matter what.

Does anyone here have a hint how to solve the issue?

I tried to deactivate/activate USB Debugging without any success, but noticed, that whatever I select, the MTP still keeps running (at least my HTC says so). Furthermore I realized that in the device manager I see the "HTC Android Phone USB Device" in DVD/CD-ROM drives section and "MTP" in "Other Devices". Tried to update the drivers - either cannot find any appropriate drivers or does not change anything. Tried to disable MTP -> phone is not anymore connected as CD, but cannot see it in Explorer at all anymore.

Though, I cannot find any options to disable MTP. With my previous laptop (Windows 7) everything worked properly.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem and again be able to see the phone as a storage device, access it, and to synchronize/exchange data with the PC back and forth?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

These Chinese originated ROMs have a Win installer in them, if you tap the CDRom icon on ur PC it will install a " partner" Win app on your PC.
Just ignore it! When you connect your Phone to PC under the ADB settings notification just tick connect as USB storage and the next time you reconnect ur phone ( depending on the ROM) it will appear as another 2 or 1 additional USB drive.
Mine is a home cooked Lenovo Vibe 2.0 ROM (S939) and Lenovo has in most of its ROM this Win app installers. But I don't use them because they are cumbersome Chinese chracters only app. I used MOBOROBO if you happen to transfer file a lot from external sdcard.